# Why does my SwipeView page not change when I change the Tab in the TabBar in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

So, I'm trying to create a traditional look for my QML application which simply consists of a `TabBar` and a `SwipeView`. There's also another component which essentially boils down to a button click which should result in a new tab in the `TabBar` and a new page in the `SwipeView`. This works, except that when I click on the previous tab (there's a static tab and page when the app starts up), the page in the view doesn't change.

Here's my QML file -

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

ColumnLayout {
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Component {
        id: tabButton
        TabButton {
            width: implicitWidth
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: resultListView
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "green"
        }
    }
    SwipeView {
        id: tabBarLayout
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        interactive: false
        currentIndex: 0
        LogArea {
            id: logArea
        }
    }
    TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: tabBarLayout.currentIndex
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("log")
            width: implicitWidth
        }

        Connections {
            target: qmlBridge
            onLoadResultTab: {
                tabBar.addItem(tabButton.createObject(tabBar, {text: qsTr("search - " + term)}))
                tabBarLayout.addItem(resultListView.createObject())
                tabBarLayout.incrementCurrentIndex()
                console.log("Added new item...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `onLoadResultTab` signal is invoked when the button is clicked. As you can see, I'm adding a new `TabButton` and incrementing the current index and then creating another component which is just a simple `Rectangle` for now. Now, when I click on the "log" button, the `SwipeView` doesn't change its page to the one corresponding to the log tab. Could anyone point out what's the issue here?

Comment: Hey its me from Reddit - you sent me a message. I tried to get something running but I couldn't quickly. Can you put together something that i can run. If you look in your `QT_DIR` which you exported to get it running, there is `bin/qmlscene`. Can you make a qml example that doesn't require a backend and runs with just qmlscene (i.e no need for qmlBridge) and I'll take a look. For instance you will need to replace `LogArea` with a rectangle or something...
OR... if you push a working project with the go backend to github, I'll take a look.

Comment: You are missing a connection from the TabBar index changes to the SwipeView, connect the TabBar currentIndex to the SwipeView currentIndex.